# Stuck ERC-20 Transaction - reversal did not work

Tags: transactions, ether, erc-20, gas, pending-transactions

I tried two days ago to send some BAT and ETH to my Coinbase account from my Klever Wallet (which, after this, I will never use again - they seem to be living in 2015 with the gwei fees they charged).

Here is the Tx for the BAT: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x90de87670ac8e608e8c5f9e9d2efd5452768070748af56cdccd646df7c3eed32

Here is the Tx for the ETH: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x406dcf1de6886bacf0b2a851e2eddaa2bcb179b4ba6720a076b2823b720ce59d

With this said, I realised my issue was my wallet set a fee of 57GWEI, which is low as hell on today’s standards. I decided to jump onto MEW, and send myself 0ETH for 200GWEI and same nonce as the BAT transaction as this was done first.

Here is the 0ETH Tx: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4e1dace2046dd65f4700a1a74b33f9615d12590414ad878820bd4ce3a87d7e22

This last one got confirmed, yet none of the other two got cancelled!! What do I do now?

Comment: The last one (0x4e1dac..) uses a different wallet than the first two. To cancel a transaction they have to be sent from the same addresss.